# llvm.stackprotect of LLVM

Tags: llvm

I just get started with LLVM. I am reading the code for stack protection which is located in lib/CodeGen/StackProtector.cpp. In this file, the InsertStackProtectors function will insert a call to llvm.stackprotect to the code:

```
  //   entry:
  //     StackGuardSlot = alloca i8*
  //     StackGuard = load __stack_chk_guard
  //     call void @llvm.stackprotect.create(StackGuard, StackGuardSlot)
  // ...(Skip some lines)
  CallInst::
    Create(Intrinsic::getDeclaration(M, Intrinsic::stackprotector),
           Args, "", InsPt);
```

This llvm.strackprotect(http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-stackprotector-intrinsic) seems to be an intrinsic function of llvm, so I tried to find the source code of this function. However, I cannot find it...

I do find one line definition of this function in include/llvm/IR/Intrinsics.td, but it does not tell how it is implemented.

So my questions are:

- Where can I find the code for this llvm.strackprotect function?
- What is the purpose of these *.td files?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.td` file is LLVM's use of code-generation to reduce the amount of boilerplate code. In this particular case, `./include/llvm/IR/Intrinsics.gen` is generated in the build directory and contains code describing the intrinsics specified in the `.td` file.

As for `stackprotector`, there's a bunch of code in the backend for handling it. See for instance `lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/SelectionDAGBuilder.cpp` - in `SelectionDAGBuilder::visitIntrinsicCall` it generates the actual DAG nodes that implement this intrinsic